# Is the usage like "sugar free" correct in grammar?

Tags: grammar

I ask a question in Unix&Linux forum recently, I say: "I want to make sure that it's not malware contained", moments later, a senior community fellow rewrite that sentence to " I want to make sure that it doesn't contain malware."

I think the grammar of "malware contained" is similar to "sugar free", is this kind of usage correct?

Comment: "Sugar free" is correct.  But "malware contained" is not.  Very few adjectives in English can follow the modified noun.

Comment: "Sugar Free" is accepted due to its pervasive use in advertising, not because it represents a common language pattern in English.

Comment: Why didn't you just write "I want to make sure that it's malware free"? That would have been perfecly fine. Conversely, you can't say "it's not sugar contained", either.

Comment: @RegDwigнt But you could say *sugar-containing*. At least it one could in the UK.

Comment: @RegDwigнt I simply speak what comes into my mind. My intuition told me its right to speak in this way(although its not).

Comment: But you could say *malware infected*.

Comment: @bib I try to speak like a native speaker of English, but I didn't expect it's wrong in grammar.

Comment: @GEdgar That's not strictly true, for instance if one considers compounds using non-participial adjectives.

Answer (score 4):

The two are very different. "Malware contained" would mean "contained by malware," not "containing malware." (And would be an unusual usage.) It can get a little confusing how these noun-adjective adjectival phrases imply that something is adjective [from/by/of] the noun, e.g. "free of sugar." Also note that these phrases should be hyphenated in most contexts:

> a sugar-free donut

Answer (score 3):

***Sugar-free*** is certainly a well understood, everyday idiom, as in *sugar-free lemonade* etc. Note also we have ***alcohol-free beer***, ***lead-free petrol***,***virus-free software*** etc.

Where ***contain*** is used in this way we normally attach the present participle - ***containing*** e.g. ***a paracetomol-containing cold remedy***, ***arsenic-containing rat poison***, ***asbestos-containing insulation material*** etc.

Answer (score 1):

There are many terms that revolves around the usage of (*noun*)-free. In this case, sugar-free would mean:

> Something that has little or no quantity of sugar.

However, malware contained would mean that there is the presence of malware itself, and that it would not mean malware-free, because malware-free would mean something that is free of malware.

You could also say that

> "I want to make sure that it is *malware-free*".

Answer (score 1):

I'd write simply "make sure that it contains no malware" but the (awkward, not recommended) analogue to *sugar-free* here is *malware-containing*.

*To contain* means "to hold" or "to have in itself".  We can say *mineral-containing water* or *mineral-holding water* but not "mineral-held water" and not "water which is mineral-held".

If you consider the verbs *hold* and *contain*, it becomes clear that two entities are (implicitly) involved: the holder|container and the thing that is held|contained.

When we form an adjective from the past-participle of these bare infinitives (contained, held), the adjective refers to the *passive* entity (that which is held) not to the *active* entity (that which holds).

To refer to the active entity adjectivally, we must use the present participle: *holding, containing*.

*Malware-containing software.*

But that is awkward, as I wrote earlier, and it's better to say "does not contain", that is, better to express the idea with subject and verb than with subject and adjective.

Answer (score 1):

You say,

> *I think the grammar of "malware contained" is similar to "sugar free"*

You are wrong.

1. "malware-contained" is similar to "sugar-freed".
2. You can invert both of them:

"sugar freed" ---> freed from sugar

"malware contained" ---> contained by malware

As Ronald pointed out, you can say "I want to make sure it is malware-free."